# How to replace sagas during run time?

Tags: generator, redux-saga

I have a React Native app that may connect to different API endpoints. Some users may need to change API endpoint on the run time, without restarting the app. All the API requests are bound to sagas, and the root saga looks like

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield [
    takeLatest([
      ONE_REQUEST,
      ANOTHER_REQUEST,
      // a bunch of sagas that are responsible for API querying
    ], api); // <- here, api is global.
  ];
}
```

so it can run along with the newly instantiated Redux store:

```
import rootSaga from './sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));

// other stuff, and finally

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga).done.catch(console.error);
```

The problem is, once executed, the Store, let alone sagas, can never be updated.

I tried to pass `api` to root saga as the first argument:

```
export default function* rootSaga(baseUrl = DEFAULT_API_URL) {
  const api = create({
    baseUrl,
    // other stuff that is required by apisauce
  });

  yield [
    takeLatest([
      ONE_REQUEST,
      ANOTHER_REQUEST,
      // a bunch of sagas that are responsible for API querying
    ], api); // <- here, api is instantiated per every yield* of rootSaga.
  ];
}
```

I tried to refer to the generator itself from within a function executed per a certain action type:

```
yield [
  takeLatest([
    ONE_REQUEST,
    ANOTHER_REQUEST,
    // a bunch of sagas that are responsible for API querying
  ], api); // <- here, api is instantiated per every yield* of rootSaga.

  takeEvery([
    REPLACE_API // <- the action I would dispatch to replace API endpoint
  ], ({endpoint}) => {
    yield cancel(rootSaga);
    yield* rootSaga(endpoint); // <- the new API endpoint
  });
];
```

But it didn't work. I also tried a bunch of other tactics, but none really worked either. And I looked up the docs for something similar to Redux's `replaceReducer`, but there's nothing like this for redux-saga, which makes me feel that it can be done using only proper sequence yielded by root saga generator.

So, is there a general approach to this problem? Is it possible to re-instantiate root saga on the run time?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can add the endpoint URL to the state tree and manage updating the URL based on a typical redux-saga flow.  Then, when you dispatch your REQUEST actions, just read the current end point URL from the state tree and attach that as a payload to the REQUEST action. Then, in your api saga, use that URL payload.